# sending JSON object from Android to HttpURLConnection POST request

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

im trying to send a json object that looks like this to my server {'name':joe},
and currently my code looks like this. However the json i get on my server looks like this { '{"name":joe}': '' }. so my question is how do i send the json, so it would look like {'name':joe} when i receive it on my server? my server is using nodejs. i want to get that name by request.body.name. any help would be appreciated

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:3000/users/user");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
            String jsonString = "{\"name\":" + this.mName + "}";
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            os.write(jsonString.getBytes());
            os.flush();



            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (conn.getInputStream())));

            String output;
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(output);
                response.append('\r');
            }
            mes = response.toString();
            conn.disconnect();

            if (mes!=null && !mes.isEmpty()){
                return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return false;
    }
```

EDIT:after changing application/x-www-form-urlencoded to application/json. i keep getting FileNorFoundException, and server returns response code 400

Comment: String jsonString = "{\"name\":" + this.mName + "}"; try to change this with something  String jsonString = "'name\':" + this.mName";

Answer (score 0):

SanuoXeu change this line in your code it will work

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: when changing application/json to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. i keep getting FileNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:3000/users/user");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");    

                DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
                jsonParam.put("name",this.mName);
                os.write(jsonParam.getBytes());
                os.flush();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        (conn.getInputStream())));

                String output;
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(output);
                    response.append('\r');
                }
                mes = response.toString();
                conn.disconnect();

                if (mes!=null && !mes.isEmpty()){
                    return true;
                }else {
                    return false;
                }

            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are doing well .

Its gonna be hard if you are willing to send your data as JSON by concatenating strings .

```
private String makeJson(String name) {

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try {
            json.put("name", name);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return json.toString();
    }
```

Then change this line :

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help ....

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:3000/users/user");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");

         /***************** add this code **********************/
            JSONObject ap = new JSONObject();
            ap.put("name","Joe");

            OutputStreamWriter ap_osw= new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            ap_osw.write(ap.toString());
            ap_osw.flush();
            ap_osw.close();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (conn.getInputStream())));

            String output;
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(output);
                response.append('\r');
            }
            mes = response.toString();
            conn.disconnect();

            if (mes!=null && !mes.isEmpty()){
                return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return false;
    }
```